# Converting an object into a JSON string

Tags: python, converting, json

I wrote a Python method to convert an object and a subset of its attributes into a JSON string with a given field as the key.

There's a lot of string concatenation, and I'm not too sure what the best way to do that in Python is.

I'm also wondering if `attr.replace('"','\"')` is sufficient to sanitize input.

```
def to_json_with_key(nodes, key, fields, insertIndex=False):
    i=0
    s="{"
    for node in nodes:
        s += '"%s":{' % getattr(node,key)
        attrs=[]
        for field in fields:
            attr = getattr(node,field)
            if not isinstance(attr,int) and not isinstance(attr,float) and not isinstance(attr,long):
                attrs.insert(0, '"%s":"%s"' % (field, attr.replace('"','\"') ))
            else:
                attrs.insert(0, '"%s":%s' % (field, attr ))

        if (insertIndex):
            s+='index:%d,' % i
            i=i+1

        s+=','.join(attrs) + "},"
    s = s.rstrip(",") + "}"
    return s
```

Sample input:

> ```
> to_json_with_key(myObj, "title", fields=["length","time_offset"], insertIndex=True)
> ```

Sample output:

> ```
> {"Introduction_to_Lists":{index:0,"length":128,"time_offset":0,
>  "Pass_by_Reference":{index:1,"length":84,"time_offset":128}}
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, python includes a json module. Use that rather then writing your own.

However, just to give some comments on your style:

```
def to_json_with_key(nodes, key, fields, insertIndex=False):
```

python recommend words_with_underscores for parameter names

```
    i=0
```

Rather then manually keeping a count use enumerate

```
    s="{"
    for node in nodes:
        s += '"%s":{' % getattr(node,key)
```

You don't check the value to make sure it is json-safe. Building strings by concatenation is not usually a good idea. Either build a list and join it or use StringIO

```
        attrs=[]
        for field in fields:
            attr = getattr(node,field)
            if not isinstance(attr,int) and not isinstance(attr,float) and not isinstance(attr,long):
```

You can pass several types in a tuple to isinstance to check several types at once.

```
                attrs.insert(0, '"%s":"%s"' % (field, attr.replace('"','\"') ))
```

This won't be sufficient. For example, you could have a \ at the end of a string. You also need to handle newlines, tabs, and other escaped characters.

```
            else:
                attrs.insert(0, '"%s":%s' % (field, attr ))
```

Why insert rather then append?

```
        if (insertIndex):
```

No need for parens

```
            s+='index:%d,' % i
            i=i+1

        s+=','.join(attrs) + "},"
    s = s.rstrip(",") + "}"
```

It would be cleaner to join a list of items rather then stripping off stray commas.

```
    return s
```